# Publishing VB.NET program with drivers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vba, publish, publishing

I have written a program in VB.NET that calibrates two [Rohde & Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohde_%26_Schwarz) and [Agilent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keysight) instruments together, which includes several instrument drivers from these companies. I can get the program to work on another computer with all of the drivers and related software already installed, but how do I package it in a way that anyone without the software or even Visual Basic/Visual Studio on their computer?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Are you currently using the included "Deploy" / "Publish" (I think various versions have all used one of those two terms for it) wizard? If so what options are you using (i.e. install from CD, install from URL, etc)?

Comment: @RobertSheahan

I am using Visual Basic Express 2010; I am using the wizard to set it up to install from a CD with framework 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I use Professional 2010, which supports "Solutions" and provides a "Setup Project" template that I can put in my Solution to handle Setup. VB Express 2010 apparently does not support either. You might still get things to work, but it sounds like doing what you want to do easily is one of the selling points for the more expensive version :-(

You might as well try, though. What follows isn't "how to do it" so much as "how I'd try if I had to do it". First, if you reasonably can, set up a virtual machine with a minimal install of Windows to test against, it's nice to take a snapshot and reset it to fresh between tests, or at least periodically.

Start with your "Project"-"Properties" menu choice, and go to the "Publish" tab. For testing purposes, install from a URL and pick one that is on a network drive. Click the prerequisites tab and make sure you have not only whatever dependencies your project has, but also any dependencies the Instruments' device drivers have. Hopefully you'll be able to skip using their setup files, but that won't happen if a dependency they require is missing. Make sure you have the "create setup program to install prerequisites" checkbox checked (if Express even has it! Not sure on that). I'm not sure if it's better to have the prerequisite installer copy the files from the internet or from your project directory, you might have to experiment with that.

Also on the "Project"-"Properties" menu choice, and go to the "References" tab. Make sure the drivers for your instruments have been added here. The hope is that the installer will recognize them as a dependency and package enough of them with your application setup program get them working on the client machine. You may have to use the "browse" tab to locate these drivers, and again, some trial and error might lead to a combination that works.

When you've made your best guess, try installing on your test target. Watch the errors carefully, they are huge and hard to read, but often will have an explanation of what is missing buried somewhere inside. It can take several iterations going back and forth with the references to catch them all. And again, it might not even be possible to do it this way with Express.

If that doesn't work, you may have to resort to shipping the driver install programs from the vendor and either requiring the user to install them, or making your own installer program that just runs the installers for the drivers and then runs the installer for your (separate) main program. You can add files to a project that just get copied to the install directory. It isn't ideal, but with a bit of work I think it's a viable solution.

Good luck, and please report back how it goes. I'm not likely to downgrade from Professional, but I'm curious how far Express can go.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This was quite helpful advice! I was able to include all of the files for the IVI.NET drivers (2 of 3) by going under project properties > Publish > Application Files, all of the references and *.dll files came up and are now included. I am still trying to figure out how to include the IVI-COM references though. To use this driver I had to install Agilent VISA, and this is huge and I don't know what I need/what I don't, so right now the I have the installers in a separate folder that the user has to install manually. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add the setups of those drivers in the resources of your app. On runtime of your app, make it validate if the drivers are installed, if not then it can extract the setup(s) of the drivers to a temp folder and run their setup.
The other method is that you can use Install Wizards, a very famous example is the Install Shield Wizard.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about adding the set ups? Just select the dll under "Add Resource" in the "Resources" tab?

Comment: Well if you have executable files, then add them or if you have *.dll(s) then add those to the resources